# jsonschema pointer to data pointer

Tags: javascript, json, object, converters, jsonschema

I have the following **jsonSchema**: (note that there are fields called 'properties' and its not 'json-schema peoperties(who represent fields)'

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "image": {
            "type": "string",
            "media": {
                "binaryEncoding": "base64",
                "type": "image/jpeg"
            }
        },
        "properties": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "nameObj": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "properties": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "firstName": {
                    "title": "First Name",
                    "type": "string",
                    "maxLength": 100
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## **data looks like**:

```
    {
    "name": "person1",
    "properties": "myProperties",
    "nameObj": {
        "properties": "nameProperties",
        "firstName:": "myPerson"
    }
}
```

I have dotnotation path to field "firstName" under the schema:

`properties.nameObj.properties.firstName`

and I want to convert it to data path as below:

```
nameObj.firstName
```

I cant only ignore 'properties' fields because (as you can see in above schema) 'properties' can be a data field name or a json-schema property.

JaveScript example will be greate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ive crated a function to convert this path:

```
        function schemaPathToEntityPath(schema,path) {
    let fields = path.split('.');
    let dataFields;
    for (let field of fields) {
        if (field === 'properties') {
            //if its json-schema property
            if (schema.hasOwnProperty('type') && schema.type === 'object') {
                //go next level inside schema
                schema = schema[field];
                continue;
            }

        }

        //if field actually exist in schema
        if(schema.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
            //go next level inside schema
            schema = schema[field];
            //for the first time just add field, later add '.' + field
            dataFields = dataFields ? dataFields += '.' + field : field;
        }
    }
    return dataFields;
}
```

**example:**

```
       let schema={
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "image": {
            "type": "string",
            "media": {
                "binaryEncoding": "base64",
                "type": "image/jpeg"
            }
        },
        "properties": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "nameObj": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "properties": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "firstName": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "maxLength": 100
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

let schemaPath1='properties.nameObj.properties.firstName'
let schemaPath2='properties.nameObj.properties.properties'

console.log(schemaPathToEntityPath(schema,schemaPath1));
//output= nameObj.firstName

console.log(schemaPathToEntityPath(schema,schemaPath2));
//output= nameObj.properties
```